# Python: determine if three text strings stored in a dataframe have any words in common

Tags: python, string, pandas, text, split

Say I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
      A             B               C
0     mom;dad;son;  sister;son;     yes;no;maybe;
1     dad;          daughter;niece; no;snow;
2     son;dad;      cat;son;dad;    tree;dad;son;
3     daughter;mom; niece;          referee;
4     dad;daughter; cat;            dad;
```

And you want to check if, between columns `A`, `B`, and `C`, there is a common word, and create a column `D` with `1` if there is and `0` if there isn't any. For a word to be common, it's enough for it to appear in just two of the three columns.

The outcome should be:

```
      A             B               C              D
0     mom;dad;son;  sister;son;     yes;no;maybe;  1
1     dad;          daughter;niece; no;snow;       0
2     son;dad;      cat;son;dad;    tree;dad;son;  1
3     daughter;mom; niece;          referee;       0
4     dad;daughter; cat;            dad;           1
```

I am trying to implement this by doing:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    w1=row['A'].split(';')
    w2=row['B'].split(';')
    w3=row['C'].split(';')

    if len(set(w1).intersection(w2))>0 or len(set(w1).intersection(w3))>0 or len(set(w2).intersection(w3))>0:
        df['D'][index]==1
    else:
        df['D'][index]==0
```

However, the resulting `D` column only bears `0` because (possibly) I am not comparing each individual word in w1 to the others in w2 and w3. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `stack` + `pandas.Series.str.get_dummies`

```
df.assign(
    D=df.stack().str.get_dummies(';').sum(level=0).gt(1).any(1).astype(int)
)

               A                B              C  D
0   mom;dad;son;      sister;son;  yes;no;maybe;  1
1           dad;  daughter;niece;       no;snow;  0
2       son;dad;     cat;son;dad;  tree;dad;son;  1
3  daughter;mom;           niece;       referee;  0
4  dad;daughter;             cat;           dad;  1
```

---

### Details

Notice that when we stack and get dummies, the interim result looks like this:

```
     cat  dad  daughter  maybe  mom  niece  no  referee  sister  snow  son  tree  yes
0 A    0    1         0      0    1      0   0        0       0     0    1     0    0
  B    0    0         0      0    0      0   0        0       1     0    1     0    0
  C    0    0         0      1    0      0   1        0       0     0    0     0    1
1 A    0    1         0      0    0      0   0        0       0     0    0     0    0
  B    0    0         1      0    0      1   0        0       0     0    0     0    0
  C    0    0         0      0    0      0   1        0       0     1    0     0    0
2 A    0    1         0      0    0      0   0        0       0     0    1     0    0
  B    1    1         0      0    0      0   0        0       0     0    1     0    0
  C    0    1         0      0    0      0   0        0       0     0    1     1    0
3 A    0    0         1      0    1      0   0        0       0     0    0     0    0
  B    0    0         0      0    0      1   0        0       0     0    0     0    0
  C    0    0         0      0    0      0   0        1       0     0    0     0    0
4 A    0    1         1      0    0      0   0        0       0     0    0     0    0
  B    1    0         0      0    0      0   0        0       0     0    0     0    0
  C    0    1         0      0    0      0   0        0       0     0    0     0    0
```

Where the prior columns are embedded in the second level of the index.  So I want to sum over the first level in order to see how many times that word appears.

That summation interim looks like:

```
   cat  dad  daughter  maybe  mom  niece  no  referee  sister  snow  son  tree  yes
0    0    1         0      1    1      0   1        0       1     0    2     0    1
1    0    1         1      0    0      1   1        0       0     1    0     0    0
2    1    3         0      0    0      0   0        0       0     0    3     1    0
3    0    0         1      0    1      1   0        1       0     0    0     0    0
4    1    2         1      0    0      0   0        0       0     0    0     0    0
```

Notice that we catch `'son'` in row 1, `'dad'` and `'son'` in row 3 and so on.

If it appears in more than 1 column (hence `gt(1)`) then I want to count it as a `1` (hence `any(1).astype(int)`).

Comment: This is an exceptionally neat piece of code that might benefit from a touch more explanation.

Comment: Very nice solution :) +1

Comment: How does the `D=df.stack()` part work if your column has a name such as `There are spaces in this header`? Also, how do you apply this to a selection of an existing dataframe, e.g. without creating a new one?

Comment: @FaCoffee you can do a couple of things.  One, you can drop the results of `df.stack().str.get_dummies(';').sum(level=0).gt(1).any(1).astype(int)` directly into the dataframe with `df['Name with spaces'] = ...` or you can continue to leverage the `assign` method by unpacking a dictionary `df.assign(**{'Name with spaces': df.stack().str.get_dummies(';').sum(level=0).gt(1).any(1).astype(int)})`

Comment: Can you have a list in place of `Name with spaces` if you have multiple columns to process that have spaces in their headers?

Comment: Ahh, I think you mean that your example dataframe with columns `['A', 'B', 'C']` is actually `['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3']`?  If I'm right, then yes, your suggestion should work.  `df[['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3']].stack()...`

Answer (score 4):

This one-liner creates what you need, using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

df['D'] = df.applymap(lambda x: [i for i in x.split(';') if i]).apply(lambda x: int(Counter(x.A+x.B+x.C).most_common(1)[0][1]!=1), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use your code by fixing a typo: replace `==` with `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def find_common(row):
     A_list=set(row['A'].rsplit(';')[:-1])
     B_list=set(row['B'].rsplit(';')[:-1])
     C_list=set(row['C'].rsplit(';')[:-1])
     if ((len(A_list.intersection(B_list))) or (len(B_list.intersection(C_list))) or (len(A_list.intersection(C_list)))):
        return 1
     else: 
        return 0
```

`df['D']=df.apply(find_common,axis=1)`